# PIR sensor doesn't work properly

Tags: arduino

Month ago I bought a PIR sensor in DX (http://www.dx.com/p/ir-infrared-motion-detection-sensor-module-dc-5v-20v-139624#.VNOiqDVXa00)

It is HC-SR501 model.

I have connected the positive to 5v, as say in the pin of sensor, the ground to gnd and the signal to pin 2.

I use the following code

```
byte ledPin = 13;
byte motionPin = 2;
byte senseMotion = 0;

void setup(){
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motionPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("Serial inicializado");
}

void loop(){
  senseMotion = digitalRead(motionPin);
    if (senseMotion == HIGH) { 
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Motion detected");
    } else {                    
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}
```

this program detect if there are motion and if it is then turn on internal arduino led (pin 13)

But when I download it to Arduino UNO, the internal led arduino is blink every time, with a 1-2 second as interval. I move my hand in PIR range and it doesn't response.

I have read that when the program download to Arduino it is normal that the led blink because it is calibrating, But in my case the led doesn't stop blink and it doesn't response to any motion.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any output on the serial monitor?

Comment: Yes, when the led is turned on I can see: "Motion detected" motion detected in serial monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor was broken. I bought another PIR sensor form the same page and again the error still ocurrs, but then I bought other sensor in other shop and now with the same code and connection it works properly.

Comment: I find it useful to have a multimeter to test the output voltage from components such as a motion sensor to isolate where the problem is occurring.